# AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding different results in JAVA and JNI

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-ndk, openssl

I have a Java code for encryption which looks like this

```
byte[] encrypt(byte[] clearData) {
   byte[] passwordKey = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E,0x0f};
   byte[] rawSecretKey = new byte[]{0x34, (byte) 0xA4, 0x16, 0x09, 0x77, (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xB4, 0x31,
                                                0x75, 0x12, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0xDD, (byte) 0xCA, 0x15, (byte) 0xAB, (byte) 0xBA};
   secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(passwordKey, "AES");
   ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(rawSecretKey);
   Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
   aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);

   byte[] encryptedData;
   encryptedData = aesCipher.doFinal(clearData);

   return encryptedData;
}
```

I have to port this code to JNI. I have build openssl and made JNI wrapper function which looks like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_axon_voiceassistant_utils_JNIUtils_getcr(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jbyteArray srcData)
    {
        int srcLen=env->GetArrayLength(srcData);
        unsigned char* indata = new unsigned char[srcLen];
        env->GetByteArrayRegion (srcData, 0, srcLen, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(indata));

        const unsigned char ukey[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E,0x0f};
        unsigned char iv [] = {0x34, 0xA4, 0x16, 0x09, 0x77,0x85, 0xB4, 0x31,
                               0x75, 0x12, 0x92,0xDD, 0xCA, 0x15, 0xAB, 0xBA};

        const size_t encs_length = ((srcLen + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
        unsigned char enc_data[encs_length];
        memset(enc_data, 0, sizeof(enc_data));


        AES_KEY key;
        memset(&key, 0, sizeof(AES_KEY));

        AES_set_encrypt_key(ukey, 128, &key);
        AES_cbc_encrypt(indata, enc_data, srcLen, &key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);

        jbyteArray bArray = env->NewByteArray(encs_length);
        jboolean isCopy;
        void *enc_copy = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical((jarray)bArray, &isCopy);
        memcpy(enc_copy, enc_data, encs_length);

        env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical( bArray, enc_copy, 0);

        return bArray;

    }
```

But I don't get same results with the JNI version as with the Java version. What could be the problem?

Comment: by not getting the same results, do you mean the entire encrypted result is different, or just the ending maybe?

Comment: Entire encrypted result is different

Comment: This might, in part, be a padding issue. From some research, I think `AES_cbc_encrypt` does zero-padding. This would only affect the final 16 bytes of your ciphertext, so if your data is longer than that and it all looks different, then there is at least one more problem.

Comment: @Duncan When asking the question I was testing only with short inputs. I've just tried with longer inputs and the final 16 bytes were different. Is there a solution for this padding problem?

Comment: @sinisha Well, one option is to add the padding yourself in your JNI code. PKCS #7 padding is very simple (check it out on wikipedia). Zero padding is bad news, so we don't want to change your Java code to use that. Alternatively, you can use one of the higher level EVP functions, which seem to understand padding.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks a lot. I've just implemented this and it worked :)

Comment: @sinisha  I am struggling with the same. Can you please share your code examples or share me java and jni files to mailtomistri@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've zero padded your plaintext in your JNI code:

```
const size_t encs_length = ((srcLen + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
unsigned char enc_data[encs_length];
memset(enc_data, 0, sizeof(enc_data));
```

But your Java code is using PKCS #7 padding. One of these will need to change.

Note: I think (based on some research) that `AES_cbc_encrypt` does zero padding by default, so the step where you've done this yourself might be redundant.

To fix this, either implement PKCS #7 padding by hand in your JNI code (it's actually very easy), or consider using the higher-level EVP functions, which understand how to pad data.